# Discord py more than one tasks.loop at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, discord, discord.py

How can I have more than one loop running ate the same time using the same function but using different parameters like:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
async def loop(name):
    Print(name)

loop.start("Jon")
loop.start("Joseph")
```

Is this how u pass parameters to loops?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a new `Loop` object for each loop.  You can do this by using regular function calling repeatedly instead of the decorator:

```
async def loop(name):
    print(name)

names = ["Jon", "Joseph"]

loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(name) for name in names}
```