# Discord py create a new tasks.loop object for each loop

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to run a task.loop multiple times with a Discord bot, however this is not working as the loop is already running.

I found this answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62440735/discord-py-more-than-one-tasks-loop-at-the-same-time):

```
async def loop(name):
    print(name)

names = ["Jon", "Joseph"]

loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(name) for name in names}
```

However, I can't figure it out.
I don't understand how to automatically create a new loop from this, I always get this error with this program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(name) for name in names}
  File "main.py", line 11, in <dictcomp>
    loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(name) for name in names}
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 506, in decorator
    return Loop(func, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/tasks/__init__.py", line 76, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Expected coroutine function, not {0.__name__!r}.'.format(type(self.coro)))
TypeError: Expected coroutine function, not 'str'.
```

I copied the code to try it out and pasted it into a new program, this now looks like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

async def loop(name):
    print(name)

names = ["Jon", "Joseph"]

loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(name) for name in names}#What exactly does this line do?
```

What do I have to change so that this error goes away and the loop can be executed multiple times?

Comment: Guys, pressing -1 and then not even explaining why in a comment is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda hard to explain if you don't know the basics of decorators, take a look at [this gigantic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-function-decorators-and-chain-them-together/1594484#1594484) it will hopefully clear up some things for you.

The shortest explanation that I can give is that decorators wrap your function in another function that returns a function. What you're currently doing is wrapping a `STRING` instead of a function with the decorator.

```py
async def loop(name):
    print(name)

names = ["Jon", "Joseph"]
                                 # `loop` is the coroutine we defined above
loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(loop) for name in names}
# Note that this is just a dict that holds functions, to start it
for name, coro in loops.items():
    coro.start(name)
```

If you want to start the loops directly in the dict comprehension

```py
loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(loop).start(name) for name in names}
```

I'm unsure why would you want to do such thing if you can simply do:

```py
names = ["Jon", "Joseph"]

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def loop():
    for name in names:
        print(name)


loop.start()
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to give you the answer to your indirect question in another answer.
Your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

@Łukasz Kwieciński - I have to answer you like this because the answer is too long

It is only an example,
I have defined a loop in my main script that should be called multiple times:

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def AutoRole(ctx, guild:discord.guild, role:discord.Role, members:discord.Member, startTime:int, endTime:int):
  if (datetime.datetime.now().hour+1 >= startTime) and (datetime.datetime.now().hour+1 < endTime):
    for memberID in members:
      member = guild.get_member(memberID)
      await member.add_roles(role)
  else:
    for memberID in members:
      member = guild.get_member(memberID)
      await member.remove_roles(role)
```

I call this one like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def startAR(ctx, role:discord.Role)
  if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
    startTime = X #I retrieve this data from a database
    endTime = Y #I retrieve this data from a database
    members = Z #I retrieve this data from a database
    AutoRole.start(ctx, ctx.guild, role, members, startTime, endTime)
    echo.info(ctx, "Startet AutoRole " + role.name)
  else:
    await echo.warning(ctx, "You need Admin Role to edit roles")
```

Since you can create multiple AutoRoles, this loop must be called again, and different values will be supplied.

But for the Test your Answer works fine and it helps me:

```
async def loop(name):
    print(name)

names = ["Jon", "Joseph"]
                                 # `loop` is the coroutine we defined above
loops = {name: tasks.loop(seconds=10)(loop) for name in names}
# Note that this is just a dict that holds functions, to start it
for name, coro in loops.items():
    coro.start(name)
```